# How to uninstall ruby installed using ruby-build

Tags: ruby

I've installed ruby-1.9.2-p290 using ruby-build. I used the command `ruby-build 1.9.2-p290 ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290`

Now, How do I uninstall this version of ruby?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just remove this directory?

```
rm -r ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290
```

Ruby-build is small program, it just builds Ruby from source and puts it in directory. To use it, you need to setup your env variables, just how rbenv does.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering, are there any other extra steps like RVM.

Answer (score 7):

ruby-build now adds an uninstall command to rbenv to handle the removal of ruby versions, if you want to avoid manual `rm -r` (which might be considered risky). For removing ruby version `1.9.2-p290` you would run the following:

```
rbenv uninstall 1.9.2-p290
```